# trackingProfile configuration for specific activityDefinitionId (dynamic)

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I want the ability to enable and disable the custom tracking in some specific workflows using the trackingProfile.  So, I will only create the entries for the ones that I want to track, like this:

```
 <trackingProfile name="MyTracking">
   <workflow activityDefinitionId="MyWorkflow1">
    <customTrackingQueries>
       <customTrackingQuery name="*" activityName="*"/>
     </customTrackingQueries>
   </workflow>
   <workflow activityDefinitionId="MyWorkflow2">
    <customTrackingQueries>
       <customTrackingQuery name="*" activityName="*"/>
     </customTrackingQueries>
   </workflow>
 </trackingProfile>
```

We load the workflow dinamically from the disk using ActivityXamlServices.Load.  So, do you know what activityDefinitionId is in this case? I used the path and it didn't work...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Activity Definition Id is actually the ID of the activity obtained from Loading an XAML file using ActivityXamlServices.Load.
[Activity from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activity.aspx).